# How to get an asset all details in AEM with API request?

Tags: aem, workfront-api

I am using AEM API in my automation. We published a file from workfront to AEM. That file have multiple information:

```
1. Basic
2. Test1
3. test2
4. etc
```

When I hit the api:

```
/api/assets/..../abc.pdf.json
```

I am getting very less information under the properties and metadata section. (In short, it does not have Test1, Test2 and other tab information)

Is there any way to fetch all these from aem API's? It will reduce my overhead to validate these details from UI Automation.

Answer (score 0):

First of look checkout the metadata nodes of file for the desired data to be present. I would rather prefer writing a custom servlet in AEM which takes in path parameter as an asset path and gives back the response back in desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The following API returns all the JCR content in API response:

```
<baseURL>/content/dam/path to that file.-1.json
```

Comment: you can use .infinity.json to get all values in the returned JSON